Create SUMPRODUCT formula from excel to DAX Measure Power BI
I've created a formula in excel : =SUMPRODUCT(AK14:AK37,AM14:AM37) that gives a result of 98.77%(converted to percentage). I tried using sumx function and it works only in when applied in a matrix(filter context) but not in the total.
AK14:AK37 = Column1, AM14:AM37 = Column3
Excel:

power BI:

Please help me :) TIA !

Can you give the formula of your measure?

Each cell in the matrix visual is a filter context within which your SUMX formula will calculate.
It looks like PowerBI is just summing up the percentages since it isn't sure what to do at the total line. In that case try tell PowerBI what should be done for the total line by using an IF statement.
Measure = 
IF(NOT HASONEVALUE(DimTable[DimColumn]),
    CALCULATE(SUMX(FactSales, [FactColumn1] * [FactColumn2]), REMOVEFILTERS(DimTable[DimColumn])),
    SUMX(FactTable, [FactColumn1] * [FactColumn2]))

This will tell PowerBI that: if the row has more than one value then remove filters on the dimension column and calculate the measure you have defined on all of the data.
The second part of the IF block tells PowerBI to calculate SUMX as normal, relying on the filtering in the visual if the cell has a single value.
Another option is HASONEFILTER=TRUE() rather than HASONEVALUE because the total line will only have a single filter for the column dimension, and not two filters for the row and column applied.
You need to use CALCULATE on the total line formula to remove the row filters.
